# how can I convert a number to a string, extract each digit, cast it again to integers, and add them all together (e.g. 1+2+3+4+5+6) in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm thinking I have to create a view that stores the cast as text and I have to utilize the substring function in sql but I'm a little lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Instead of going through text, you could calculate it: `n%10` (modulo) gives the last digit, `n/10` removes it. You do need a loop however.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a string to rows using `unnest()` and `string_to_array()` and then add the digits using `sum()`

```
select sum(digit::int)
from unnest(string_to_array(12345::text, null)) as x(digit)
```

Comment: Wow, learned a new thing!  No idea you could pass null as argument for string_to_array like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the number

```
select to_char(12345, '0+0+0+0+0+0+0');
    to_char
----------------
  0+0+1+2+3+4+5
```

**Inside a function**, you can run this statement as a dynamic query to get the result

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || to_char(12345, '0+0+0+0+0+0+0');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE qsum AS (
   SELECT 123456 AS num,
          0 AS sum
UNION ALL
   SELECT num / 10,
          sum + num % 10
   FROM qsum
   WHERE num > 0
)
SELECT max(sum)
FROM qsum;

 max 
═════
  21
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get there with `regexp_split_to_table`, using `?!^` to split on every character.

`regexp_split_to_table(cast(<your column> as text),'(?!^)') as s`

Here's a simple [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/370f40/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can shred the string to rows, then sum:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(n as INTEGER))
FROM regexp_split_to_table('01234567', '') as n
```

But this sort of string math is probably a better fit for calling code. If you are trying to validate *new* records, consider doing it outside of the DB.

Comment: You didn't test that, did you?